# How to adjust background image to screen's size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background image cover the whole screen width and height, and I can't seem to get it right with the height.

I am following [these](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) tips to achive it but I don't get it right. It just goes as high as the inner div content can go.

This is the html and css, you can see it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh8b4ddx/1/) as well:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="background-container">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="container">
            JOIN US!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    height: 50px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.bg {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431578500526-4d9613015464?q=80&fm=jpg&s=169b4f4e6f3882a03b6b93b2e6848052) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Body tags are not full-height by default. You need to specify that.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jh8b4ddx/4/)**

To prevent the resulting scroll, remove margin and and padding as well.

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jh8b4ddx/5/)**

Comment: that worked, but instead of doing that for just the `html` and `body` tags had to do it to a wrapping div that container the `.bg` div. BUT, there's a navigation bar as direct child of `body` and that creates a scrolling bar I'd like to get rid of. I am going to update the original post to illustrate it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If feasible please add `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%` to your `.bg` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the .bg is just that container you see. If you want the background like you are describing change .bg to body and it works

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431578500526-4d9613015464?q=80&fm=jpg&s=169b4f4e6f3882a03b6b93b2e6848052) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    //add this if you want it to stay fixed
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

or you can make the .bg position absolute or fixed so it'll take 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

The default html gets a margin so it will not stretch till the end, so add margin:0 and padding: 0, for stretching till the corners of the browser. Next the width:100vw; implies that 100% of your viewport width so as to make a responsive webdesign, similarly height:100vh; 100% of the viewport height

Add a CSS rule

```
 body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
 }
```

Comment: @SergeyDenisov added comment.